# How to send a hex bytes to a serial port in debian?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a device connected in my raspi3

```
pi@raspberrypi:/home $ sudo bash main.sh
%s\t%s\n 0 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
%s\t%s\n 1 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
%s\t%s\n 2 Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp.
%s\t%s\n 3 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
%s\t%s\n 4 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
%s\t%s\n 5 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Target device:

%s\t%s\n 1 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
pi@raspberrypi:/home $
```

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

usbArray=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    usbArray+=( "$line" )
done < <( lsusb )


for i in "${!usbArray[@]}"; do 

  echo "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${usbArray[$i]}"

done

echo ""
echo "Target device:"
echo ""

for i in "${!usbArray[@]}"; do 

  if [[ ${usbArray[$i]} == *"China Resource Semico"* ]]; then
    echo "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${usbArray[$i]}"
  fi

done
```

From the device protocol I see:

```
1.read master version 
sent: 5A 00 00 0d 0a 71
reply: A5 00+ "MASTER-FW:v1.0\r\n" + CS
```

So I have to send `5A 00 00 0d 0a 71` as data, not string, and I will receive a hex data response, I have this done in windows using cport library, but I don't know how to do this in debian(raspi3)

any idea?

Comment: `bash` is the wrong tool to communicate with serial ports. But it has no problems with sending hexstrings: `printf '\x5A\x00\x00\x0d\x0a\x71'` will do that.

Comment: I don't get the idea how to implement that print

Comment: `printf` is a Bash builtin and a standalone executable from the _coreutils_ package as well. You needn't implement it.

Comment: You're looking for something that's approximately the reverse of `od -x`, then?

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the `usbArray` to a suitable escaped string using `printf`:

```
printf ' \\x%s' "${usbArray[@]}"
```

This produces `\x5A\x00\x00\x0d\x0a\x71`.

Then pass that as argument to *another* `printf`, to interpret those as escape codes:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(printf '\\x%s' "${usbArray[@]}")"
```

To demonstrate that we have the correct output, inspect it using `od`:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(printf '\\x%s' "${usbArray[@]}")" | od -t x1
0000000 5a 00 00 0d 0a 71 0a
0000007
```